# Key / Value fields module where you can choose the type?

Tags: 7, entities

Is there a module which creates a field where you can choose the field type of the key and also the value during content type creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module to achieve that functionality:

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can be attached.
>
> A field collection is internally represented as an entity, which is embedded in the host entity. Thus, if desired field collections may be viewed and edited separately too.

The idea is:

1. Create a Field Collection.
2. Add key/value fields to it with the field types of your choice.
3. Add a Field Collection field to the content type you want these key/value fields on.
4. Set the source of that Field Collection field to the new Field Collection you've just created.
5. Repeat for whatever other content types you need to.

Comment: Thanks, I've always tried to avoid the field collection because it creates an actual entity from the fields. It's a shame you can't group fields without doing this.

Comment: Yeah Field Collection is a weird one (I try to avoid it to wherever possible), but short of writing your own field type I think it's the simplest way to get what you're looking for

Comment: As an update to this - if you're looking to create nodes programmatically, I'd certainly recommend you avoid this module - use entity reference and views and a separate content type. (EVA allows you to embed views as a field) I just found out the hard way that field collection isn't the best solution to this problem!

Comment: And furthermore, if you want 0 instances of your field collection (that is, allow optional instances of your field collection to be specified), it seems you can't